# How to condense a 2 page statement of purpose to 500 words?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I have a well written statement of purpose that is about 2 pages in length, single spaced and 12 point font, which were the requirements of a few programs that I applied to. One of them, however, needs a statement that is only 500 words maximum. Any suggestions for effectively condensing this to 500 words and still having it be a solid statement of purpose? Having the same issue with my diversity statement as well.

Comment: Determine what the top 2-3 things you want the admissions committee to understand about you after reading the SOP. Then focus the text on those items.

Answer (score 5):

- Print it
- Highlight the key sentences ('claims')
- Write a bullet list from these sentences
- Delete those that are redundant or unimportant
- Extend each bullet point to a short paragraph by adding supporting statements to each key sentence
- If you run out of space, combine key sentences into broader statements or use less supporting statements

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  Variant: ask *someone else* to hit the bullet or outline version with the highlighter.